# What is the entirety of breadth of road called?

Tags: civil-engineering, terminology, highway-engineering

As **roadway** *consists of a width of road on which a vehicle is not restricted by any physical barriers or separation to move laterally* <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriageway)</sup>, what is a similar term which encompasses the width of the entire road's infrastructure - barriers, drainage ditches, sound screens, generally the entirety of terrain allocated for construction as a road is built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of online sources use the term road reserve to encompass the road, associated infrastructure, such as drainage and spare land for additional lanes in the future. The width of this would be the road reserve width.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the US this is commonly referred to as the Right-of-Way (property line to property line on either side of the roadway). Or, if the roadway right-of-way is wider than needed for construction, it may be referred to as the limits of construction.